# method printf is not applicable for the arguments

Tags: java, printf

I was doing the example in Core Java(Chinese translation version) and type the same with the code in the book.

> System.out.printf("After year %d, your balance is %,.2f%n",
>   year,balance);

But Eclipse says there is an error:

> The method printf(String, Object[]) in the type PrintStream is not
>   applicable for the arguments (String, int, double)

How can I make this right?

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple syntax error. You are not providing the correct types for the method parameters. Check that a the type of all parameters match the method signature.

Try this:

```
System.out.printf("After year %d, your balance is %,.2f%n", new Object[]  {year,balance});
```

Comment: Normally printf only print one arguments, but I just want to use two arguments. how can I make 'int, double' to 'object[]'?

Answer (score 0):

Or use

```
Integer year;
Double balance;
```

and the printf will be OK (and remain as simple as it is now).

printf requires

```
printf(String format, Object... arg)
```

but int and double do not declare an Object.